# Switching majors

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions

I am an undergraduate student studying mathematics. I am thinking of switching to engineering for masters or phd programs. The problem is I do not have a single engineering course. I do have knowledge of programming in C. I  do not know if it makes difference, I have a few physics courses as well. I however have more than one year before I graduate.

Which engineering fields are possible to go from the background I have? How can I strengthen the possibility to go into good programs despite such programs?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that you would need to do (and a few rhetorical questions to ask yourself):

- Talk to the admissions people relevant to the graduate studies you are wishing to do. A key question here is: Do you have the prerequisites they require?
- Go to the profiles of any professor in that faulty, particularly looking at their research interests and read some of the research papers they have completed.  Also, pay particular attention to the titles of the research degrees they have supervised (sometimes, this is available).  A key question here would be: Which engineering field of research matches your interests, expertise and background?
- Last, but not least, what is your 'end-game'? What is the overall career/research plan?